# Iterating through models for a select field with Rivet.js & Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, rivets.js

I'm attempting to populate a select field with options using bootstrapped data.  I'm encountering an issue when binding my array of models to the jQuery select object...

**The HTML**

```
<select data-each-project="projects" id="project-selection">
    <option data-value="project:description"></option>
</select>
```

**The Binding**

```
project_array = new Array()

_.each projects, (project) ->
    projects_array.push project

rivets.bind @el.select, projects:projects_array
```

**The Result**

I receive an error indicating that the object has no .on method -> which it doesn't because it is an array of models not a model it self...

How should this really be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subscribe to an iteration binding rivets does two things:

1. Subscribes to the entire array so if it changes it will rerun the
   iteration
2. Subscribe to all children of the array that need binding

Rivets isn't subscribing to your children because you are not using any bindings that require it.

project:description = non-subscribe binding

project.description = subscribe binding

If you don't want to subscribe to array changes (I think that's what you're asking for) you can do `data-each-project=":projects"`

Comment: Could you provide a bit of details around how it subscribes to the entire array?